# Haskell: Stuck writing a function to replicate`elem`

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

For my very first lecture in haskell we where given a series of problems. One of them is to return True when n number is present in a list, or False otherwise. I managed to get what i think is half-way there but am getting different compile errors and am pretty frustated because I can even understand what they mean.

So far I have done the following

```
// No problem with this function
matches :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]    // This function is to return the matches 
matches x y = [a | a <-y, a==x]     // ie. main> 1 [1,3,5,7,1,4] outputs [1,1]

// Here am stuck
myelem :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
myelem x [] = False
myelem x (y:ys)
 | x == y = y : x myelem ys       // Am not sure about recursion as 
                                  // we have not yet covered
```

Obviously this is for a class so **please do not** post the answer. But maybe a few examples that will help me reason about both the workings of Haskell and how to approach the problem. Any pointer will be massively appreciated.

---

**SOLUTION**

```
matches :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
matches x y = [a | a <-y, a==x]

myelem :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
myelem x [] = False
myelem x (y:ys)
 | x == y = True
 | otherwise = myelem x (ys)
```

*Cheers guys*

Comment: @pelotom, @Jeremiah Willcock, @9000: Thanks so much guys, am just finding it quite challenging to switch my reasoning from imperative to declarative. Just to clarify; when `myelem x (ys)` is executed does it actually deletes elements from the list until empty, or is it just evaluating the remaining elements on the list until none left?

Comment: @Carlos: In a pure functional language such as Haskell, functions can never "delete" anything, because that would be a side-effect, violating purity. In order to see how a functional list works, it helps to write it out in its nested form: `[1,2,3,4]` is actually `1:(2:(3:(4:[])))`. In other words, this list is made up of `1` prepended to *another* list, `2:(3:(4:[]))`, which in turn is made up of `2` prepended to *another* list, and so on. Each inner list is "unaware" of the outer lists referring to it.

Comment: @Carlos: For example, `let xs = [1,2,3] in (4:xs, 5:xs)`... this results in a pair of lists, `([4,1,2,3],[5,1,2,3])`, which *share* the same inner list `xs = [1,2,3]`. Recursive functions which act on lists mirror this nested form. They pattern match on a list which looks like `x:xs`, do something with `x`, recurse on the inner list `xs`, and so on, until bottoming out at `[]`. Nothing is altered by a pattern match, it's simply analyzing the list into its components.

Comment: @pelotom: wow buddy thanks a lot, I really appreciate the great explanation, time and effort you putted into my question. Good karma to you.

Comment: Whenever you have a function that looks at the items in a list one at a time and spits out something, `foldr` is usually a good way to go. I suggest you rewrite your function with a fold, as this is a very good exercise for getting used to Haskell and the functional programming mentality.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for your suggestion am sure is very accurate. But as I say in the first line; "I have just been to the very first lecture" on Haskell. According to my class syllabus we aren't introduced to `foldr` until 2 weeks from now. Yet again, thanks for pointing it out i will certainly look head of our current stage and try to give it a go ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your last equation:

```
myelem x (y:ys)
 | x == y = y : x myelem ys
```

There are two problems here:

1. If you want to use `myelem` as an infix operator, you have to surround it in backticks, like so:

   ```
   x `myelem` ys
   ```
2. Given that's what you meant, the right hand side of your equation doesn't type check; the list constructor `(:)` requires its second argument to be a list, not a `Bool`. Furthermore, `(:)` constructs a list, and `myelem` is supposed to return a `Bool`!

Think about what you're trying to do. If `x == y`, you just want to return `True`, right? And `otherwise`, you want to return the result of checking the rest of the list (`ys`). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually pretty close to the right answer.  I see two main issues, though.  One is that the call to `myelem` on the last line of code needs to have backquotes around it to make it infix (`` x `myelem` ys ``) or a prefix call without backquotes (`myelem x ys`).  Also, you do not want to prepend `y` to the result of the recursive call.  You actually do not need a condition on your second pattern: just think about what `myelem x (y:ys)` should return using simple Boolean operations and the recursive call you already have there.

Answer (score 1):

You try to concat an `Int` and a `Bool` in the last line; think again.

You never return `True` from `myelem`; sometimes it is appropriate.

Once these issues are fixed, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write your function using some combination of the following functions (there are at least two ways of doing it using the functions below):

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

removes elements from a list unless they satisfy some set of criteria

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
```

returns whether the list is empty or not

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
```

is logical negation

```
or :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

returns True if a list of Bool contains one or more True values.

Obviously, you've solved your problem, but it might help you to explore other ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could also define your `myelem` function in terms of `matches`.

- What will matches return if the item is not in the list?
- What will matches return if the item is in the list once? twice? many times?
- Do you care about the entire return value in the second case? (hint: no)